# How to merge two tex files so that each have their own refs

Tags: citing, combine, multiple-files

My paper has a supplementary file, and I want to submit it on arXiv. I first tried to convert them to PDF and merge them using Adobe software. However arXiv enforces that I send the actual source code. 
Back to the issue, if I simply use

```
...
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
{ \scriptsize
\bibliography{refs} 
}

\newpage
\input{SuppMaterial}
```

I dont get what I want, I mean the refs block get repeated, since my SuppMaterial also has references, I get the whole reference at the end of the SuppMaterial as well.
How can I merge these two so that each file has its own refs block?(The first file starts and ends with its refs, then the second one starts and ends with its own refs)

To be more precise, here is an example of how these  two files look like: 
`main.tex` looks something like this :

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{subcaption}     % for subfigures
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sci}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes,snakes,positioning,matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.text}
\usepackage[sort&compress,square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibsection%
{
  \section*{\refname
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}}
}
\makeatother

% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

%
% paper title

\title{Title}
%

%\author{XXX, YYY,ZZZ%,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}% <-this % stops a space
}


% use for special paper notices
%\IEEEspecialpapernotice{(Invited Paper)}




% make the title area
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
Here is the abstract
\end{abstract}

% Note that keywords are not normally used for peerreview papers.
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Deep Learning, Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNS), Efficiency. 
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}

...

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
{ \scriptsize
\bibliography{refs} 
}
\end{document}
```

`supp.tex` looks something like this :

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{subcaption}     % for subfigures
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=red}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sci}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes,snakes,positioning,matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.text}

% To number supplemental material with 'S': 
\renewcommand{\thepage}{S\arabic{page}}  
\renewcommand{\thesection}{S\arabic{section}}   
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}   
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}


\begin{document}

\title{Title}

%\author{X, Y, Z,%,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}% <-this % stops a space


\maketitle

% \begin{abstract}
% \end{abstract}


\section{Discussions}

\subsection{Subject 1}

...

\ifCLASSOPTIONcaptionsoff
  \newpage
\fi


\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
{ \scriptsize
\bibliography{refs} 
}
% \begin{thebibliography}{10}

% \end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and the ref.bib which is used by both of them looks like this :

```
@inproceedings{AlexKrizhevsky_imgnet_2012,
   author = {Alex, Krizhevsky and Sutskever, Ilya and Geoffrey, E. Hinton},
   title = {ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks},
   pages = {1097--1105},
   booktitle = {NIPS},
   year = {2012},
}

@inproceedings{Ba_DoDeepNets_nd_B_Deep_2014,
   author = {Ba, Jimmy and Caruana, Rich},
   title = {Do deep nets really need to be deep?},
   booktitle = {NIPS},
   pages = {2654-2662},
   type = {Conference Proceedings}
}

@inproceedings{Bucilua_Model_compression_2006,
   author = {Buciluǎ, Cristian and Caruana, Rich and Niculescu-Mizil, Alexandru},
   title = {Model compression},
   booktitle = {SIGKDD},
   publisher = {ACM},
   pages = {535-541},
   ISBN = {1595933395},
   type = {Conference Proceedings}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered including the supplementary material via the pdfpages package instead?

Comment: @DaiBowen: Yes, and that works, but the problem is, including the pdf and also all the images, will exceed the limitation of 10MB and thus the submission will be rejected

Comment: @Breeze but... that problem is to arise in any case, isn't it? If you send the source code, that will also exceed the 10MB, will it not?

Comment: @rthymaro: Actually you are correct, I removed all files concerning the supp.tex and used its pdf instead. I didn't face any problem. Guess that was the easiest way to go. Thanks DaiBowen for reminding me and thymaro for pointing that out again :) apart from this hack, It would be nice to see other ways as well.